Read pkl object from S3
I have a model object that was created in the Statsmodels library.
I have a local copy and can open it.
from statsmodels.iolib.smpickle import load_pickle

new_results = load_pickle("SQS_FullScoring_20240501.pkl")

new_results

<statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.BinaryResultsWrapper at 0x1eff60fc910>

I then uploaded the pkl file to an s3 bucket and want to load the model object from s3
`
import pickle
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

print(s3)
# s3.ServiceResource()

my_pickle = pickle.loads(s3.Bucket("datascience-drt-models").Object("SQS_FullScoring_20240501.pickle").get()['Body'].read())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoCredentialsError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [54], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 my_pickle = pickle.loads(s3.Bucket("datascience-drt-models").Object("SQS_FullScoring_20240501.pickle").get()['Body'].read())

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py:580, in ResourceFactory._create_action.<locals>.do_action(self, *args, **kwargs)`

I've also tried similar stuff and hve not had luck.
Does anyone have suggestion on this?
import the pickle object

NoCredentialsError would seem to suggest you haven't setup your AWS credentials correctly... you're not even able to get the data from the bucket until you resolve that.
